# Defining conditional variables in a PHP class

Tags: php, class, oop, variables, conditional-statements

I've written a PHP class for connecting to PayPal based on this tutorial - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/05/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/

It works great when using hard coded credentials, but my admin interface allows me to enable or disable sandbox mode and to enter credentials for both the sandbox and live accounts.

My problem is that this is my first foray into OOP, and I'm struggling with conditional statements within a class. For example, I need to do this within a class, and have $endpoint available within the class;

```
if( $sandbox ) {
    $endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
} else {
    $endpoint = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';
}
```

Comment: how you have defined the variables??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the variables within a constructor, that way you can set the variable outside the scope of the class.

```
class Paypal(){

   protected $sandbox;

    public function __construct($sandbox) {
        $this->sandbox = $sandbox;
    }

    ....
    ....

    if($this->sandbox) {
      //do something
    }
    else {
      //do something else
    }

    ...
}
```

Then in you script do the following:

```
<?php
include('/path/to/Paypal.php');

public function checkSandbox() {
    //check if sandbox is enabled or not
    if($enabled)
        return true;
    return false;
}    

$sandbox = checkSandbox();

$paypal = new Paypal($sandbox);
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I'd rather define $endpoint and $sandbox within the class if possible, as I don't want to have to define them every time I create a new instance.

Comment: @chips From what I understand of you problem, you'll at least need to declare $sandbox outside of the class as there is no way of know from inside the class whether not it is enabled. So you can omit the $endpoint variable from the constructor but $sandbox will need to stay. Classes are not procedural, they can't tell if something has been check or unchecked.

Comment: @chips I adjusted my answer too

Comment: Thanks again, Nicholas Suddenly everything falls into place, I didn't know that procedural coding was not possible inside a class! In that case, is it possible to call a function from within the class that would define the variables, or would I have to do something like $paypal = new Paypal( $myfunction );

Comment: It is possible if the function is defined within another class, but then you need to import the other class into you current Paypal class. In your instance it is much easier just to have $sandbox equal to the return value of simple function. See the above changes ^_^

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I eventually got me head around it!

Answer (score 0):

in `oop` the class variables are accessed like - `$this->sandbox` & `$this->endpoint`. and you should define them first in the class.

```
public $sandbox;
public $endpoint;
```